# Can I enter a timecode instead of a frame number in the timeline to navigate?

Tags: timeline

Yes. Moving the indicator to the specific spot works well by writing a specific frame number in the Blender Timeline's current frame value box.

However, I am in a situation where I want to move the indicator by typing the time code today.

I know how to do this in After Effects,

[image]

but I'm not sure about it in Blender.
As far as I know, in Blender, pressing Ctrl + T on the timeline will change the way just it is displayed.

[image]

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: [This](https://github.com/RayMairlot/Timecode) may help?

Comment: Your recommended add-on works just fine in my situation. Thank you.